# chaining queryselectors in puppteer

Tags: jquery-selectors, puppeteer

how can I chain query selectors in puppteer like we do in protractor?

```
return this.page.$$(".stop.departed").$$eval(".station",el=>el.innerText)
```

I get `TypeError: this.page.$$(...).$$eval is not a function`

My Html is

```
 <div class="stop departed">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="station">London
    </div>
    <div class="scheduled">Dept. 10:47
    </div>
  </div>    
 </div>
 <div class="stop departed">
  <div class="left">
    <div class="station">Paris
    </div>
    <div class="scheduled">Dept. 12:47
    </div>
  </div>    
 </div>
```

I want to get all station names in a list ["London", "Paris"].

Comment: What is more important — do you want ti get all the stations in a list or do you want to have chaining?

Comment: The end result of getting all the stations in a list is the goal so I can compare if they are correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both methods, [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageselector-1), and [`elementHandle.$$eval()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#elementhandleevalselector-pagefunction-args) return promises, so you must [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) them both.

The functions also both run [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) on the selectors, so you must specify the element by index before running the next operation (or iterate through all indexes).

The following example will return the first station at the first stop:

```
const first_station = await ( await page.$$( '.stop.departed' ) )[0].$$eval( '.station', el => el[0].innerText );

console.log( first_station ); // London
```

Alternatively, you can use the following example to obtain an array of stations for each stop:

```
const stations = await Promise.all(
    ( await page.$$( '.stop.departed' ) ).map( el => el.$$eval( '.station', el => el.map( el => el.innerText ) ) )
);

console.log( stations.length );    // 2
console.log( stations[0].length ); // 1
console.log( stations[1].length ); // 1
console.log( stations[0][0] );     // London
console.log( stations[1][0] );     // Paris
```

Or if every stop only has one station, you can use:

```
const stations = await Promise.all(
    ( await page.$$( '.stop.departed' ) ).map( el => el.$$eval( '.station', el => el[0].innerText ) )
);

console.log( stations.length ); // 2
console.log( stations[0] );     // London
console.log( stations[1] );     // Paris
```

Comment: But how do I know the number of elements will be returned by the first selector so I can index it correctly before running the next operation ?

Comment: @Mateen-Hussain You can use `( await page.$$( '.stop.departed' ) ).length` to obtain the number of elements of the first selector. I have updated my answer with more examples on how to obtain all of the results.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Protractor makes such calls easy by simply chaining them like `$$(..).$$(..).getText()` may be Puppeteer should apply that level of abstraction too so its easy for beginners like me :)